# Courage in Christians just about to be crucified

Tags: history, crucifixion, persecution

I saw on a YouTube channel a reference to a certain man that interviewed early Christians just about to be crucified. He said he saw only courage in them. Does anyone have a reference to this or know the name of this man?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about "just about to be crucified", but your source might be thinking of Pliny the Younger, who interrogated and tried Christians and wrote a well-known letter on the subject to the Emperor Trajan. I see the reference "Epistolae X96"

Comment: Where can I find that reference?

Comment: The letters of Pliny the Younger are available (e.g.) in Penguin paperbacks.

Comment: Ok. Good. Thank you very much.

Comment: I found that letter on the internet. I didn’t find what I was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

**Courage in Christians just about to be crucified**

*Does anyone have a reference to this or know the name of this man?*

Too many examples to go though, to know who he was referencing.

The Early Church abounds with stories and legends about the courage of the martyrs facing death either through crucifixion or some other means. It is not limited to those martyrs of the Early Church.

By tradition, both St. Peter and his brother St. Andrew were both crucified.

Take St. Andrew for example:

> The Apostle continued by saying that he had “ardently awaited” the cross. Today men flee far from any kind of suffering, any kind of fight against their own passions, any kind of renunciation. For them to live is to enjoy a good life.
>
> Andrew, however, ardently awaited his own cross because he understood that what counts in life is not the pleasure he has, but the sacrifice he makes. This is what gives meaning to life. Therefore, the truly supernatural man is a friend of the cross, as St. Louis Marie de Montfort said so well.
>
> Andrew not only accepted the crosses given him during his life, but he looked for them. This is clear when he said that he had “always sought” sacrifice. Then, in the hour of his martyrdom he had that marvelous reaction – he said that his “heart had long awaited” the crucifixion. Which one of us can say a thing like that? What a sublime courage Andrew had in saying these words, which, however, came to his lips naturally and with complete serenity because he had always lived in preparation for that.
>
> Our Lord said that there is no greater friend than one who would give his life for the other. No one can give a greater proof of friendship with Our Lord than to desire the cross like this Apostle did.
>
> **Prepared for Heaven**
>
> He continued: “Take me, O Cross! Embrace me. Release me from my life among men. Bring me quickly and diligently to the Master. Through you He will receive me, He, Who through you has saved me.” Can any soul be more prepared for the beatific vision than one who would make this prayer at the hour of his death?
>
> After his crucifixion, Andrew remained two days hanging on the cross before dying. While he was on the cross he was teaching the people who came to watch him die. How priceless that teaching was! What "cathedra" could ever be more sublime to teach people from? These were his last words:
>
> > “Lord, eternal King of glory, receive me hanging from the wood of this sweet cross. Thou who art my God, whom I have seen, do not permit them to loosen me from the cross. Do this for me, O Lord, for I know the virtue of Thy Holy Cross.”
>
> - [Saint Andrew the Apostle](https://americaneedsfatima.org/articles/saint-andrew-the-apostle)

St. Peter was traditionally seen as being crucified upside down because he felt unworthy of by crucified in the same manner as his Saviour.

But legend is a little more complex than right here.

According to the apocryphal *Acts of Peter*, Saint Peter met the risen Christ while he was fleeing persecution in Rome. According to the tradition, Peter asked him, "Lord, where are you going?" ([***Domine, quo vadis?***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domine,_quo_vadis%3F)). Christ answered, "I am going to Roam be crucified again". After this peter regain his courage and went back to Rome to be crucified.

[image: Domine, quo vadis]

***Domine, quo vadis***

The ancient historian Josephus describes how Roman soldiers would amuse themselves by crucifying criminals in different positions, and it is likely that this would have been known to the author of the *Acts of Peter*. The position attributed to Peter's crucifixion is thus plausible, either as having happened historically or as being an invention by the author of the Acts of Peter.

And then there is the martyrdom of [Saints Cosmas and Damian](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/04403e.htm).

> Early Christian physicians and martyrs whose feast is celebrated on 27 September. They were twins, born in Arabia, and practised the art of healing in the seaport Ægea, now Ayash (Ajass), on the Gulf of Iskanderun in Cilicia, Asia Minor, and attained a great reputation. They accepted no pay for their services and were, therefore, called anargyroi, "the silverless". In this way they brought many to the Catholic Faith. When the Diocletian persecution began, the Prefect Lysias had Cosmas and Damian arrested, and ordered them to recant. They remained constant under torture, in a miraculous manner suffered no injury from water, fire, air, nor on the cross, and were finally beheaded with the sword. Their three brothers, Anthimus, Leontius, and Euprepius died as martyrs with them. The execution took place 27 September, probably in the year 287. At a later date a number of fables grew up about them, connected in part with their relics. The remains of the martyrs were buried in the city of Cyrus in Syria; the Emperor Justinian I (527-565) sumptuously restored the city in their honour. Having been cured of a dangerous illness by the intercession of Cosmas and Damian, Justinian, in gratitude for their aid, rebuilt and adorned their church at Constantinople, and it became a celebrated place of pilgrimage. At Rome Pope Felix IV (526-530) erected a church in their honour, the mosaics of which are still among the most valuable art remains of the city. The Greek Church celebrates the feast of Saints Cosmas and Damian on 1 July, 17 October, and 1 November, and venerates three pairs of saints of the same name and profession. Cosmas and Damian are regarded as the patrons of physicians and surgeons and are sometimes represented with medical emblems. They are invoked in the Canon of the Mass and in the Litany of the Saints.

Do not think it stops in the Early Church. Do not forget the 26 Martyrs of Japan of February 5, 1597.

> The 26 Martyrs of Japan were a group of Catholics who were executed by crucifixion on February 5, 1597, in Nagasaki, Japan. Their martyrdom is especially significant in the history of the Catholic Church in Japan.
>
> A promising beginning to Catholic missions in Japan – with perhaps as many as 300,000 Catholics by the end of the 16th century – met complications from competition between the missionary groups, political difficulty between Portugal and Spain and factions within the government of Japan. Christianity was suppressed and it was during this time that the 26 martyrs were executed. By 1630, Catholicism had been driven underground. When Christian missionaries returned to Japan 250 years later, they found a community of "hidden Catholics" that had survived underground.
>
> **Martyrdom**
>
> In the aftermath of the San Felipe incident of 1596, 26 Catholics – four Spaniards, one Mexican, one Portuguese from India (all of whom were Franciscan missionaries), three Japanese Jesuits, and 17 Japanese members of the Third Order of St. Francis, including three young boys who served as altar boys for the missionary-priests – were, on the orders of Toyotomi Hideyoshi, arrested in January 1597, tortured, physically mutilated, and paraded through villages across Japan, then on February 5, 1597, executed by crucifixion, impaled with lances while tied to crosses on a hill that overlooks Nagasaki city.
>
> After the persecution of 1597, there were sporadic instances of martyrdom until 1614, in all about 70. Fifty-five Catholics were martyred in Nagasaki on September 10, 1632, in what became known as the Great Genna Martyrdom. At this time Catholicism was officially outlawed. The Church remained without clergy and theological teaching disintegrated until the arrival of Western missionaries in the 19th century. - [26 Martyrs of Japan](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/26_Martyrs_of_Japan#:%7E:text=The%2026%20Martyrs%20of%20Japan%20(Japanese%3A%20%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E4%BA%8C%E5%8D%81%E5%85%AD,the%20Catholic%20Church%20in%20Japan.))

**And the youngest, a boy of 12 embraced his own cross!**

> In 1597 Jesuits and Franciscans were taken prisoner in the capital (the Jesuits were released soon due to their connection with the court) and twenty-six Christians, Japanese and foreigners, were executed in Nagasaki, becoming the first martyrs in Japan. The Rev. Sigfrid Schneider describes an incident from the martyrdom on February 5, 1597," On the way up the hill a nobleman tempted the youngest boy, Louis Ibaragi, who was only twelve years old to renounce his faith, He would not yield but eagerly asked: 'Where is my cross?' When they pointed out the smallest one to him he immediately embraced it and held on to it as a child clings to his toy." (Sigfried Schneider, Ofm, The 26 Martyrs of Japan, Chuo Press, 1980, p. 16) -[The Martyrs of Japan](http://satucket.com/lectionary/Japan_martyrs.htm)

If Our Lord Jesus was crucified on the Cross, it is not impossible that the two last **Two Witnesses of the Apocalypse** may equally be crucified in the Name and love of Christ.

The Cross is ever present in the hearts and minds of his followers.